# NSDictionary: error Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdictionary, swift-playground

I was playing with an idea in the Playground. This idea NSDictionaries used as a way to "keep" data.

I started creating a `variable` called `layer` type `[String:[String:String]]`.

So, an error occurred. I'm an hour trying to solve, and could not find the error reason happen. I am new to Swift.

```
var layers: [String:[String:String]]!

layers["key"] = ["layer":"layer"]
layers["key2"] = ["asd":"12312"]

print(layers)
```

[image]

Could someone help me? Or tell me how can I get the end result of my NSDictionaries?

Comment: By the way, this is a Swift `Dictionary`, but it is not an `NSDictionary` which is a type that is available if you `import Foundation`, `import UIKit` or `import Cocoa`.  You should use Swift dictionaries where possible because `NSDictionary` is essentially type `[NSObject: AnyObject]` so you have to do more casting of types when retrieving values from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared the type of the variable `layers` but you haven't allocated storage for it yet.

Try this instead:

```
var layers = [String:[String:String]]()
```

If you insist on `layers` being an *implicitly unwrapped optional*, then you could initialize it this way:

```
var layers: [String:[String:String]]! = [:]
```

This would allow you to assign `nil` to it later, but that would be dangerous because it would crash if you try to use it when it is `nil`.  That is the reason for your crash.

If you want it to be optional, you should declare it with `?` so that it can be safely unwrapped:

```
var layers: [String:[String:String]]?

// Sometime later
layers = [:]

// use optional chaining to assign values, this safely does
// nothing if layers is nil    
layers?["key"] = ["layer":"layer"]
layers?["key2"] = ["asd":"12312"]

// use optional binding to unwrap layers    
if let unwrapped_layers = layers {
    print(unwrapped_layers)
}
```

Try this in a Playground, and then try commenting out the `layers = [:]` part and you will see that it doesn't crash because all accesses to `layers` are done in a safe manner that properly handle the case when `layers` is `nil`.